# classpath missing jar file even though specified

Tags: java, jdbc, clojure, jtds

I've read a number of answers on classpaths, and i can't understand why this isn't working; Notice the directory listing beforehand that shows `jdbc.jar` is clearly in the Drivers directory, and then the java command still fails.  Also, on my windows machine I can run this exact program with the same setup if i put a `;` at the end of the -cp ( `"./Drivers/*;` ).  `java -version` is `java version "1.6.0_37"`.

```
[~/test ] $ ls -1 ./Drivers/

dbdump-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
jt400.jar
jtds.jar 

[~/test ] $ java -cp "./Drivers/*"   dbdump.core input.config

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVER;instance=MSSQLSERVER;database=dbone;
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$get_connection.invoke(jdbc.clj:219)
        at dbdump.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:60)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
        at dbdump.core.main(Unknown Source)

[~/test ] $
```

Answer (score 1):

`"lib/*"` should be enough ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html)):

```
java -cp "Drivers/*" com.example.Classname
```

> Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *,
>   which is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files
>   in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. **For example, the
>   class path entry foo/* specifies all JAR files in the directory named
>   foo**.

For what it is worth, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) is how things are handled on windows.

Comment: Note that this is fine for java 6+, but on java 5 or below you have to list each jar file separately.

Comment: @amalloy That's correct. I should probably add that too my answer.

Comment: the dbdump.core is the class name (it is a clojure program) and the input.config is something i'm trying to pass to -main.... Maybe it has something to do with the way i'm passing the parameter on unix? As i mentioned it works on windows....

Answer (score 1):

java handles path same whether be it on windows or linux.

So question is if ; is working on windows why it will not work on linux.

Secondly have you tried executing the same code or program on any other linux machine.

I am presuming may be the jar is corrupt. What about pin-pointedly mentioning the jar. not just * to pick up all jars

yep what nishant mentions is the correct usage of java call. along with loading the jar we also need to call the class

Comment: Classpaths *are* handled differently on the two systems. On a linux system two paths are separated by a colon whereas on a windows system they are separated by a semicolon. Of course, for the particular example given above it won't matter as there is only one entry to the `-cp` option.

Comment: You're right... something is wrong with the Jar file.  The Jar file (as downloaded from the jtds website doesn't work, but i have another one that does.  They are both version 1.3.1 however the manifest is slightly different and possibly other things.  I'm trying to diff the jars to find out why the officially downloaded one doesn't work with my clojure app.